# sending long text files to server

Tags: c++

I'm trying to send a long text file from the client side to the server using these lines:

```
FILE *trans = fopen(filename, "rb");
unsigned char *linha2 = (unsigned char*) malloc (sizeof(unsigned char)* 65536);
send(ConnectSocket, filename, (int)strlen(filename), 0);
long counter=0;
long read;
while(counter < lSize){ // lSize is the length of the file's content
    read = fread_s(linha2,  65536, sizeof(char),  65536, trans);
    counter += send(ConnectSocket, (char*)linha2, read, 0); // marked line
}
```

When I execute it, the full string isn't fully sent. And, when I put a break point on the marked line, and then I press Continue I'm the full string is sent. Why please?

**OS:** Windows 7 SP1.

**IDE:** Visual Studio 2013.

Comment: `the server` What "server"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`send` does not guarantee that all bytes will be sent. Its return value tells you how much was sent out of what you requested (and I can pretty much guarantee that it won't be all 65KB!). You should keep going until all your outgoing buffer is sent.

Read the documentation for functions that you use.

Comment: then, can you advise me how to proceed to send data? I've tried to sleep few seconds after sent, but this wouldn't work.

Comment: @Luciekulza: Read the documentation. It typically has examples. And there are literally hundreds of thousands of examples on how to use `send`, out there on the internet. `sleep` has pretty much nothing to do with it; I already indicated what you need to do instead.